# computing angle between two 3d vectors - how to implement

Tags: c++, math, casting, implementation

I would like to compute the angle between two 3d vectors. I'm using the following equation ([source of equation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/16243-angle-between-two-vectors-in-3d)) to achieve this:

```
diffangle = atan2(norm(cross(v1,v2)),dot(v1,v2))
```

The components of v1 and v2 are given in data type float, but since I have very small angles I would like to have the difference angle in type double. My actual implementation looks like follows:

```
double angle(float x1, float y1, float z1, float x2, float y2, float z2)
{
    double dot = x1*x2 + y1*y2 + z1*z2;
    double crossX = y1*z2-z1*y2;
    double crossY = z1*x2-x1*z2;
    double crossZ = x1*y2-y1*x2;
    double norm = sqrt(crossX*crossX+crossY*crossY+crossZ*crossZ);
    return (atan2(norm,dot)/M_PI*180);
}
```

Does my implementation what it should or do I have to cast somthing or take other things into account?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: _"Does my implementation what it should or do"_ Don't you have any testcases, to check it's working properly?

Comment: Sure, but I'm wanting some feedback if I use the double type in the correct way. When I replace all 'double' with 'float' in the implementation above I get some other results for some cases. Maybe I should make an example and add it. Thanks for you comment.

Comment: You forgot a return statement...

Comment: Thanks for the remark. During the replacement of 'float' with 'double' I also replaced the 'return' :-D.

Comment: Why are you not just computing the dot product? That gives you a magnitude scaled cosine.

Comment: If you are interested in very small angles, would it not make sense to use double precision everywhere?  Returning a **double angle** based on a **single precision** vector may not be that useful

Comment: One last thing: While the cross product can give you the sine of the angle (thus making `atan2` useful over all angles), taking the *norm* of the cross product, will always give you a non-negative number. Hence, you can only measure angles between 0 and PI.

Comment: @ kec I'm only using the formula that I have found. I thought that I use it, because of its 'higher numerical stability'. See the now indicated source of the formula. @ Micky Duncan Maybe it would make sense, but unfortunally I only have the single precision. @ nimrodm In my case it is also possible that a angle larger than PI occurs, so the choice of atan2 would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the issue of accuracy: In C (and C++), floats will be promoted to double when a double in involved in the calculation (same thing for promoting from int to long int).

So the expression

```
 double z = x*y;
```

First computes `x*y` in single precision (`float`), then casts the result to `double`. To actually perform the calculation using double precision you need to cast one of the elements involved in the expression:

```
 double z = (double)x*y;
```

The simplest solution, however, would be to change the function declaration to accept `double`. This way, the `float` values would be promoted when calling the function and all calculations will use double precision.

Comment: This answer completely misses the fact that the formula is programmed incorrectly.  It should not be accepted.

Comment: Why is the formula incorrectly? [Source](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/16243-angle-between-two-vectors-in-3d)